# redirecting output of bash find and then piping to xargs.

Tags: bash, xargs

This is a script that will remove files if the volume is greater than 85%. It works fine, however, I would like to see the output of the find command in the terminal and save it to a temp file as well. If I put a -verbose on the end of the gzip command, it goes verbose, but I would like to see the files before the zip, not after.

```
volume="vol10"
mountp="/casper/vol10"
filepath="/casper/vol10/casperfile/"
fileglob="/casper/vol10/casperfile/201*"
filetemp=$(mktemp /tmp/vol10cleanup.XXXXXX)

get_volpercent() {
{ read foo ; read foo; read size used avail prct mountpoint ; } < <(df -k ${mountp}/*)
printf "%s\n" "The Percentage of $volume is $prct"
}


cd $filepath

for filerm in execution order ; do
    get_volpercent
    if [[ "$prct" > "85%" ]] ; then
        printf "%s\n" "Disk is over 85% full"
        printf "%s\n" "find $fileglob/$filerm -mtime +10 -type f | xargs gzip "
        printf "%s\n" "Zipping files"
        find $fileglob/$filerm -mtime +10 -type f -print 2>&1 | tee -a $filetemp | xargs gzip
        get_volpercent
    else
        get_volpercent
        cat $filetemp
    fi
done
```

Comment: Lotsa additional/unrelated bugs here, by the way, many relating to missing quotes. Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: Also, `find -print | xargs` is innately buggy with filenames containing spaces, filenames containing literal quote characters, filenames containing newlines, etc. See [BashFAQ #20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) (*How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?*)

Comment: @Charles - Thank you will use the shellcheck !!!

Comment: (As another example -- does your `$prct` contain `9%` or `09%` if it's one percent below `10%`? If you do a lexicographic comparison, as this code does, then `9%` will be seen as larger than `85%`, because `9` has a higher ASCII sort order than `8`).

Comment: @Charles - added -r to read, and a print0 from shellcheck and bashFAQ20 - how do I check the lexicographic comparisons.

Comment: Offhand, I think `(( 10#${prct%"%"} > 85 ))` should work -- that's a numeric comparison, not a lexicographic one, forced to be in base-10, with the `%` stripped.

Comment: ...so, shellcheck doesn't hassle you about quotes if your filenames are constant, but if in your real script they come from somewhere like `$1`, you should really be using them anyhow -- `cat "$filetemp"`, `cd "$filepath"`, `df -k "$mountp"/*`, etc. Whereas `$fileglob/$filerm` is problematic in general, since you're *relying* on globbing, but when you do an unquoted expansion you get not just globbing but string-splitting as well; to make that safe, you might need to set `IFS` to a null value to disable string-splitting (or just replace it outright with a different construct).

Comment: after your find.. add line with cat $filetemp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `/dev/tty` for printing the filename to screen? And GNU Parallel for dealing with "ugly" filenames:

```
    find $fileglob/"$filerm" -mtime +10 -type f -print | tee -a "$filetemp" /dev/tty | parallel gzip
```